# Adam Harishon's Lifespan

Tags: age, adam

I know Adam Harishon lived to be 930 years old but why did he live to be 930? Is there some kind of hidden meaning behind the years in his life like there is with other people in Tanach? Sources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Who says there's any special significance, for anyone in the Tanach for that matter?

Comment: @Josh there is a discussion on this in the Ramban and Moreh. see Ramban Bereishis 5:4.

Comment: Why did my grandmother live only to age 29? Only HaShem knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Zohar](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%90_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%90) said:

> רבי שמעון אמר, הא אתמר דדוד מלכא עד לא הוה לא הוו ליה חיים כלל, בר דאדם קדמאה יהב ליה שבעין שנין מדיליה, וכך הוה קיומיה דדוד מלכא שבעין שנין הוו, וקיומא דאדם קדמאה אלף שנין חסר שבעין, אשתכחו בהני אלף שנין קדמאי אדם הראשון ודוד מלכא, פתח ואמר (תהלים כא ד) חיים שאל ממך נתת לו אורך ימים עולם ועד, חיים שאל ממך, דא דוד מלכא, דהא כד ברא קב"ה גנתא דעדן, אטיל ביה נשמתא דדוד מלכא, ואסתכל ביה, וחמי דלית ליה חיים מדיליה כלום, וקיימא קמיה כל יומא, כיון דברא אדם הראשון, אמר הא ודאי קיומיה, ומאדם קדמאה הוו שבעין שנין דאתקיים דוד מלכא בעלמא.
>
> Rabbi Shimon saud that Dovid [HaMelech] wasn't supposed to live, so Adam Harishon gave up seventy of his years to him. So Dovid lived for 70, and Adam lived for 1000 - 70 (930). Turns out that Dovid and Adam lived for a thousand years. About that Dovid said "I borrowed (asked) life from you, You gave him a long, eternal life". "I borrowed life from you" - refers to Dovid, since when Hashem created the Garden of Eden he planted the soul of Dovid and saw that he had no life to him, and stood over him (?) all day. When Adam was created, He said "This one is clearly established", and from Adam's 70 years Dovid lived.

Comment: Who gave all the years to Shlomo, rechavam etc who also wouldn't have lived at all if David had died at birth

Comment: @DoubleAA could be that they would have had a different father?

Comment: It's not clear to me in what way they'd be the same person with at least half different genes

Comment: @DoubleAA we're dealing with "souls" here (although ... the son's soul has a connection to his father, so it still doesn't help).

Comment: @DoubleAA Once David lived, his descendants lived the years that they were assigned. Thus nothing had to be taken away from anybody.

Answer (score 0):

The Ramban (Bereishis 5:4) writes,

> והסבה באריכות ימיהם, כי אדם הראשון, מעשה ידיו של הקב"ה, נעשה בתכלית
>   השלימות 
>    בנוי, בכח, בקומה וגם אחרי שנקנס עליו שיהיה בן מות היה בטבעו לחיות זמן
>   רב וכאשר בא המבול על הארץ נתקלקל עליהם האויר, והלכו ימותם הלוך וחסור,
>   כי עד המבול היו ימיהם בארך ההוא, ויש מהם שחיו יותר מאדם ושם שנולד קודם
>   המבול חיה שש מאות, הועיל לו החוזק שנולד בו, והזיק לו האויר שנתקלקל
>   ובניו הנולדים אחר המבול נתקצרו ימותם, ושבו לארבע מאות:  ותראה שהיה זה
>   בהם עד הפלגה, וכאשר משל עליהם שנוי האוירות בהפלגה נתקצרו עוד ימיהם, כי
>   פלג, אשר בימיו נפלגה הארץ, שב לחצי ימיהם למאתים שנה ונראה כי בדורות
>   אברהם יצחק ויעקב היו הימים בעם שבעים ושמנים שנה, כאשר הזכיר משה רבינו
>   בתפלתו (תהלים צ י) אבל הצדיקים בדורותם יראת ה' תוסיף בהם ימים, כי פרעה
>   תמה על יעקב, והוא הפליג לו בימי אבותיו, כמו שאמר ולא השיגו את ימי שני
>   חיי אבותי בימי מגוריהם (להלן מז ט):
>
> ולא יכשר בעיני מאמר הרב שכתב
>   במורה הנבוכים (ב מז) כי לא היה אורך השנים רק ביחידים האלה הנזכרים,
>   ושאר בני אדם בדורות ההם היו שנות חייהם השנים הטבעיים המורגלים ואמר, כי
>   היה החדוש הזה באיש ההוא בהנהגתו ומזונו, או על דרך נס:  והנה אלה דברי
>   רוח - ולמה יהיה הנס הזה בהם, והם אינם נביאים ולא צדיקים וטובים לעשות
>   להם נס

The Ramban understands that because Adam was fashioned by god's hands (so to speak) his body was much stronger and able to live much longer. The flood somehow ruined the atmosphere and the people became weaker and the lifespan was shortened. After the Haflagah the lifespan became even shorter due to the excessive change in the atmosphere. He discredits the Rambam's understanding that not everyone (in the beginning) lived so long, only those mentioned in the Torah lived longer than others because they ate healthy diet (Rambam's altrnative: it was a miraculous phenomenon).